# How to use "throws IllegalArgumentException" in method declaration

Tags: java, illegalargumentexception

How do you write a method that has "throws IllegalArgumentEception" in the method declaration. Such like this one: If I were to only return d if d>0 otherwise throw an `IllegalArgumentException`, how would I do that? Do you use `try{}` and `catch{}` ?

```
public double getPrice(double d) throws IllegalArgumentException {

}
```

Comment: Yes you can use a `try...catch` and catch the exception or just throw if the `if` is not met.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do that simply at the beginning of the method:

```
public double getPrice(double d) throws IllegalArgumentException {
     if(d <= 0) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
     }

     // rest of code
}
```

Also the `throws IllegalArgumentException` is not really needed in the declaration of the method. This must only be done with *checked exceptions*. But `IllegalArgumentException` belongs to the *unchecked exceptions*.

For more information about those I recommend reading this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation).

Answer (score 2):

You should check the condition and if it doesn't meet throw the exception

Sample code:

```
public double getPrice(double d) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (d <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number is negative or 0");
    }

    //rest of your logic

}
```

You can learn more about Java Exception [here](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2076700/core-java/exceptions-in-java.html).